# How do I use the `--helper` flag in a rails 3 controller generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, generator, helper

The documentation from `rails generate controller` says:

```
[--helper]                # Indicates when to generate helper
                          # Default: true
```

Now, it doesn't specify how to indicate a value. So, since the default is true, that means that excluding it won't indicate false, because… true is the default. So it must either be `--helper=false` or `--helper false`, but I tried both, and they both resulted in `error  false [not found]`

The good news is that it did not generate a helper, because it was confused, so I still got the result I wanted :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the boolean options you can set it to false by prepending a --no_

Example:

rails generate controller book --no_helper

Comment: just found that myself :-D (it's `--no-helper`)

Comment: I think you can do either --no_helper or --no-helper