# Rails: don't generate helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, generator, config, helper

I know this is simple but I don't remember how to do this and wasn't able to find it on Google...

I rarely need a controller-specific helper file, so I would prefer that when I generate a Controller the helper (and helper spec) not be generated along with it.

I tried

```
#application.rb
config.generators do |g|
  g.helpers false
end
```

...but that didn't work. How do you change that?

Comment: --no_helper

See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405242/how-do-i-use-the-helper-flag-in-a-rails-3-controller-generator)

Comment: Any way to pass this in as a config option so I don't have to type it every time?

Comment: Singuler `helper` as per [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-generators). Don't know if that's all helpers or not.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are close, according to http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2011/02/understanding-the-latest-rails-benchmarks/

```
config.generators.helper = false
```

Comment: Doh. Plurality strikes again! Thanks :)   (I'll accept this answer in 7 minutes when SO will let me.)